# Cant install fglrx

Tags: ati, fglrx

I have a problem with installation `fglrx` pack

error:

```
Preparing to unpack …/fglrx_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
Moving ati dir to /etc for the fglrx-core transition
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error status 1   
 Errors were encountered while processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please translate the output into English by prepending `LC_ALL=C ` to whatever command you are running. Use the [edit] button to change your post. Also, what command do you actually run?

Comment: For anyone else with this problem who ends up here, do **NOT** restart the computer before fixing it. Otherwise, the display may not work. Just a friendly warning. :)

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the exact same problem on 14.04.2 after switching back and forth between the open and closed source video drivers. For some reason, apt-get purge didn't help, but purging the offending files manually did the trick.

In `/etc/`, you'll find the folders `ati/` and `ati.dpkg-bak/`. Backup `ati/` to `ati.bak` or something and then remove both `ati/` and `ati.dpkg-bak/`. After that, go to `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and rm the fglrx deb.

Now retry `sudo apt-get install fglrx`. It should just work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with updating the package. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but that almost did work for me, probably because problem happened while I tried to install `flgrx-updates`. I had to remove not only `flgrx`, but also leftovers from flgrx-update:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

After that came throguh, the rest was the same:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```